# Site for managing and sharing bucket lists?

Tags: webapp-rec, list, tasks

Is there a website to create, manage, and share bucket lists (things to do before you die)?

Something with sharing and badges would be great.

Comment: http://tadalist.com/ or other products from 37 signals are pretty nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://sharebuckets.com/

Funny you should ask this question, as an old work buddy of mine just launched this site like three weeks ago.

Comment: I think this makes all other answers moot :)  I will totally be signing up for this one later...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.43things.com/ may be a good place to create such a list.

Comment: this looks closer to what I want, though I wish it had soe kinda reward badge or something just so I can feel more accomplished :) thanks!

Comment: Well, they don't have badges, but they do have "cheers" - I haven't used the site enough to receive any "cheers" but I'm sure its nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://superviva.com/.

Comment: looks kinda busy and complicated, but thanks I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0):

[Schemer](https://www.schemer.com).

It's a "stealth" product from Google and ties into your Google+ Circles. A lot of what people enter is "bucket list" type stuff, but there's also a way to find things to do that are close to you or are related to your interests.